# RichFaces rich:datatable how to align left/right/center columns

Tags: java, spring

The table  on my page proposes a column with a button (defined in a css class) how does the object align in the column?
this is the piece of code:

```
    <rich:column width="30px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.det_button}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputLink value="../dist_details.jsp" 
            styleClass="button_detail" title="#{msg.dist_detail}">
            <f:param name="type" value="swd"></f:param>
            <f:param name="distributionId" value="#{distr.id}"> 
                        </f:param>
        </h:outputLink>
     </rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I answer myself, I found this solution that can be adopted on every single column, in my stylesheet:

```
.dx {
    text-align: right;
}

.sx {
    text-align: left;
}

.cx {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and on my jsf page:

```
<rich:column width = "20px" styleClass = "cx">
```